# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.1.1

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I have tried all solution i can find online, like adding mavenCentrals and all that.
I can find 5.1.1 under .gradle, but it's complaining it does not find any version after 2.3 in the repo.

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.1.1.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>     - file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.pom
>     - file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.jar
>     - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.pom
>     - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.jar
>     - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.pom
>     - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :
>   Open File

here's my build.gradle file

```js
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()


    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.4.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
                details.useVersion "15.+"
            }
            
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And I have distributionUrl = https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip in gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: Check this link "https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin" where you can see that Plugin version is "3.4.0" and Required Gradle version is "5.1.1" it means that your distributionUrl should be like "distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip" and your build tool gradle should like "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'"

Answer (score 53, accepted):

When you update Android Studio, you may receive a prompt to automatically update the Android Gradle plugin to the latest available version. You can choose to accept the update or manually specify a version based on your project's build requirements.

You should set ***PROPER*** *`classpath`* version.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    }
```

Set the Gradle version to `6.1.1` in the ***gradle-wrapper.properties*** file.

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

Read [**`Android Gradle plugin`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin).

```
 Plugin version ----> Required Gradle version

 3.1.0+ ----> 4.4+
 3.2.0  ----> 3.2.1 4.6+
 3.3.0  ----> 3.3.2 4.10.1+
 3.4.0+ ----> 5.1.1+
 4.0.1  ----> 6.1.1
```

Comment: tl;dr: Don't mix Gradle version and Android Gradle Plugin version.

Comment: I'm just confirming that this resolved this for me. I changed the classpath from `com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.1.1` to reflect the correct plugin version `4.0.1`. I'm just learning the difference between the Gradle version and the plugin version.