# Gradle sync failed-Android studio

Tags: android

```
7/29/2020

9:42 PM Gradle sync started

9:42 PM Gradle sync failed: Could not find gradle-4.0.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1).
                Searched in the following locations:
                https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.jar
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (20 s 154 ms)
```

Comment: May be this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56016387/2078074) help you.

Comment: Hi Samer. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't paste crash reports without any question.  StackOverflow is partially a social site and this could be misconstrued as being rude. Some tips to help out with posting. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Kind Regards.