# Intellij getting SocketTimeoutException while trying to resolve dependencies with gradle on open network

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

Details:

- No proxy network
- Have tried increasing timeout in gradle.properties
- Can download file from browser
- Intellij - Ultimate Edition - Build #IU-222.4167.29, built on September 13, 202
- Gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties - gradle-7.4.2
- Same behaviour seen with Android Studio
- Not exactly sure since when problem exists as I had commented out `task clean` for sometime and started seeing the problem after I invalidated cache by clearing files.

Here is my build.gradle file details:

```
 buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.7.10"
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.10' }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
 Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 795 ms

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom'.
               > Read timed out
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.10.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.10.pom'.
               > Read timed out

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:84)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$400(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:111)

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
.
.
Cause 1: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2.
Required by:
    project :
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadByCoords(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:144)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.create(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.create(DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.RedirectingGradleMetadataModuleMetadataSource.create(RedirectingGradleMetadataModuleMetadataSource.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveStaticDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:245)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.doResolveComponentMetaData(MavenResolver.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ExternalResourceResolver.java:475)
    .
    .
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AbstractExternalResourceAccessor.withContent(AbstractExternalResourceAccessor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.withContent(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor$DownloadOperation.call(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:122)
Cause 2: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10.
Required by:
    project :
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.10.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadByCoords(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:144)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.create(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.create(DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.RedirectingGradleMetadataModuleMetadataSource.create(RedirectingGradleMetadataModuleMetadataSource.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveStaticDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:245)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.doResolveComponentMetaData(MavenResolver.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ExternalResourceResolver.java:475)
    .
    .
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.10.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AbstractExternalResourceAccessor.withContent(AbstractExternalResourceAccessor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.withContent(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor$DownloadOperation.call(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:122)
    .
    .
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15m 5s

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
4:03:25 pm: Execution finished '--stacktrace'.
```

Reaching out after trying for 3 days. I'll be thankful if anyone can pinpoint the cause.

TA

Comment: It happens if you change any of the versions of dependencies in build.gradle and its incompatible (for me it was something related to Firebase). You can start by manually check if gradle-7.1.2 is downloaded in its expected location?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56016265/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle5-1-1

Comment: Yeah! Tried various combinations already.
Even for new project created with flutter I'm seeing the same.
So far was trying on Fedora, planning to try it on Windows now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issues are stated here https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues

In my cases I had to add following line to ~/.zshrc file

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true"
```